# Setting up kalman filter on basket of multiple securities which are cointegrated

Tags: cointegration, mean-reversion, kalman

I want to use mean reversion trading strategy.
I am able to find 3 stocks which are cointegrated on closing prices at daily level. Im curious on what's the trading strategy using kalman filter.
I can find literature for pair trading but not for multiple securities